# Spark Mllib - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset containing the Customer_ID and the Movies that each customer have seen.

I am analyzing the pattern over the movies. Like If customer X see movie Y then he also se movie Z.

I already group my dataset by Customer ID and I've the sample of data:

```
Customer_ID,Movie_ID
1,         2,1,3
2,         1
3,         3,6,8
```

What I want is ignore the column Customer_ID and only having the list of movies like this:

```
2,1,3
1
3,6,8
```

How can I do this? My code is:

```
 val data = sc.textFile("FILE");

    case class Movies(Customer_ID:String,Movie_ID:String);

    def csvToMyClass(line: String) = {
    val split = line.split(',');
    Movies(split(0),split(1))
    }

     val df = data.map(csvToMyClass).toDF("Customer_ID","Movie_ID");

     df.show;

    val movies = df.groupBy(col("Customer_ID")).agg(collect_list(col("Movie_ID")) as "Movie_ID").withColumn("Movie_ID", concat_ws(",", col("Movie_ID"))).rdd
```

Thanks

Comment: If use select it put the Movie_ID in different rows :( I need to have the Movies  Groupping  by Customer_ID in same row

Comment: I meant after grouping. Please show the code you used so far so it's easier to refer to.

Comment: I edited the post with my current code. Thanks!

Comment: If instead of calling `.rdd` at the end of the last line, you use `.select("Movie_ID").rdd` - doesn't that produce the result you want?

Comment: Top! Many thanks :)

Comment: This question remind me of this http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/13777/5177

Comment: Yes eliasah, I take the code from that post :)

Comment: I know, since I've written it. But I'm not sure that I understand your question

Comment: oh sorry, didn't see it. The code are very good but I'm following this article: https://www.phdata.io/getting-started-with-apache-spark-graphx-part-1/ and without the Customer_ID column my data is more similar to tutorial data