# Spark Scala - Split columns into multiple rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Following the question that I post here:

[Spark Mllib - Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328825/spark-mllib-scala?noredirect=1#comment65992094_39328825)

I've another one doubt... Is possible to transform a dataset like this:

```
2,1,3
1
3,6,8
```

Into this:

```
2,1
2,3
1,3
1
3,6
3,8
6,8
```

Basically I want to discover all the relationships between the movies. Is possible to do this?

My current code is:

```
val input = sc.textFile("PATH")
val raw = input.lines.map(_.split(",")).toArray
val twoElementArrays = raw.flatMap(_.combinations(2))
val result = twoElementArrays ++ raw.filter(_.length == 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `input` is a multi-line string.

```
scala> val raw = input.lines.map(_.split(",")).toArray
raw: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(2, 1, 3), Array(1), Array(3, 6, 8))
```

Following approach discards one-element arrays, `1` in your example.

```
scala> val twoElementArrays = raw.flatMap(_.combinations(2))
twoElementArrays: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(2, 1), Array(2, 3), Array(1, 3), Array(3, 6), Array(3, 8), Array(6, 8))
```

It can be fixed by appending filtered `raw` collection.

```
scala> val result = twoElementArrays ++ raw.filter(_.length == 1)
result: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(2, 1), Array(2, 3), Array(1, 3), Array(3, 6), Array(3, 8), Array(6, 8), Array(1))
```

Order of combinations is not relevant I believe.

---

**Update**
SparkContext.textFile returns RDD of lines, so it could be plugged in as:

```
val raw = rdd.map(_.split(","))
```

Comment: Hi Tomasz Blachut, many thanks!!! I'm getting error when I submut the raw variable... I update the code that I'm using. The error is:

error: value lines is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Comment: @PedroRodgers Well yes, I've written that input is a multi-line string, not a RDD of lines. I'll update answer with solution coded by hand but I don't have Spark on this machine to test it.

Comment: Don't worry I just remove the .lines and it works ;)

Comment: @PedroRodgers Good :) If you want you can also fiddle with Set.subsets, either nullary overload or unary one, take a look at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Set and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13116344/1879175

Comment: only one more thing: when I try to save the result to HDFS it gives me a file with [Ljava.lang.String;@44cc2153... do you what is this?

Comment: @PedroRodgers I remember some things very vaguely... What is the type of value you are trying to save? maybe run a toString or mkString, possibly as argument to .map on this thing.

Comment: I'm trying with this: result.mkString(",").saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/Output/Combinations")

But I'm getting this error: error: value mkString is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]

Comment: @PedroRodgers maybe `result.map(_.mkString(","))` ?

Comment: No problem. So a takeaway from this problem is that Scala's internal implementation of `Array`, i.e. Java's `[]` array doesn't work well with `toString` method